# Making an aws lambda public for use

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Is it there a way for exposing certain lambda functions to the public? I know this can be done via API Gateway but I would like to avoid using that service.

Basically im doing a python script that uses some `boto3` functions. Problem is that the only way of using some of those is by creating a session, which contains my AWS credentials in the code which I dont want. The lambda functions Im using are not "insecure" (they do not interact with anything else) so making them public wont be that much of a problem.

My plan is to be able to invoke a lambda function with `boto3` library, using `invoke()` which just needs the function `name` or `ARN` for working (and a `payload`).

Also, can you send HTTP/HTTPS requests to the lambda endpoint directly? Or must it pass through the API Gateway previously mentioned.

Comment: You really need API gateway as it will allow anonymous access.  Additionally it can be set up to limit the throughput / number of calls so that you don't wake up to someone having called your API 10^10 times and you got billed for that.  Depending on your use case a small EC2 might be easier and cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

A Lambda function can only be executed by the "[Invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)" API call. This API call can be made via three options -

1. Through another AWS service by adding it as a trigger - API Gateway, S3, CloudWatch and so on.
2. SDK (boto3, Node etc.) or AWS CLI
3. Through the console "Test" button.

To answer your question, you can use boto3 and you don't need to explicitly pass your credentials in code. If you have AWS CLI configured on the machine from where you run the Python code, you can create a boto client or session as mentioned [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html).

Lastly, Lambda does not have a HTTP/HTTPS endpoint. Think of it as EC2 instance but whose IP address is not known to you (it's a part of the [AWS IP ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) but can any be any arbitrary value). The only way to invoke a Lambda through a HTTPS endpoint is using API Gateway.